# Can I include an other document/fragment in my xdocreport template?

Tags: java, documentation-generation, xdocreport

I'm using XDocReport to create reports using a template like this:

```
«#foreach($developer in $developers)»«$developer.Name»
«#end»
```

My question is whether I can include an other document file in my template or not?
Example:

```
«#foreach($developer in $developers)»«$developer.Name»
«#end»
«#include("./someOtherTemplate.odf")»
```

My goal is to recursively include other documents (fragments) which are edited by end users.

I've checked the Wiki pages but I did not find this option in XDocReport. Velocity supports inclusion. Did I miss something?

Note: I am free to use any document format (.odf, .docx, etc) supported by Word or LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement is not possible with XDocReport because it means that you wish to merge several ODT files which is a very hard task. Velocity #include works for a plain text file although an ODT file is a zip which contains several XML entries, so it's not possible to use #include in the XDocReport case.